# Access Array attribute via Integer attribute in Lightning

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, expressions

I have a component...

```
<aura:component>
    <aura:attribute name="myArray" type="Object" />
    <aura:attribute name="index" type="Integer" default="0" />
    ...

    {!v.myArray[v.index]}
</aura:component>
```

Saving this markup fails with...

> Failed to save undefined: expecting a positive integer, found 'v' at
>   column 9 of expression: v.myArray[v.index]: Source

...as I can't access the array using the index attribute. **Why that and which alternative do I have?**

Comment: FYI [How do I access an array index referenced by attribute?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/125825/how-do-i-access-an-array-index-referenced-by-attribute) that has an accepted answer but a comment saying it doesn't work...

Comment: @KeithC I saw this question but the answer is no answer as it doesn't propose anything working. No idea who marked it as answered.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't.
I've asked the same question a while ago in a map context:

[Using a Map type attribute in aura:if](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/128892/using-a-map-type-attribute-in-auraif)

What you could do though is use an aura:iteration to run over the array, and inside render components with an index/value variable to be passed from the iteration, and have the component do the logic inside based on the index/value passed.

Iteration:

```
<aura:iteration items="{!v.myarray}" var="someVar" indexVar="someIndex" >
  <c:someComponent aValue="{!someVar}" anIndex="{!someIndex}" />
</aura:iteration>
```

Inner component:

```
<aura:component>
  <aura:attribute name="aValue" type="String" />
  <aura:attribute name="anIndex" type="Integer" />
  <div>
    {!v.aValue}
    {!v.anIndex}
  </div>
</aura:component>
```

Alternatively, you could read the array in an init/change event and set the result in an attribute:

Markup:

```
<aura:component>
    <aura:attribute name="myArray" type="Object" />
    <aura:attribute name="index" type="Integer" default="0" />
    <aura:attribute name="value" type="String" />
    <aura:handler name="change" value="{!v.index}" action={!c.accessArray}" />
    ...

    {!v.value}
</aura:component>
```

Controller:

```
accessArray : function(component) {
    var myArray = component.get('v.myArray');
    var index = component.get('v.index');
    component.set('v.value', myArray[index]);
}
```