# How to form expression in lightning component in salesforce

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I have two attribute in lightning component. one is List and second is Integer attribute and I want to pass dynamic value of list.

```
< aura:attribute name = "index" type ="Integer" />

< aura:attribute name = "DataList" type ="List" />  

< c:myChild_CMP obj="{!v.DataList[index]}" /> 

//getting Error here
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Failed to save MyCMP.cmp: expecting a positive integer, found 'v' at column 39 of expression: v.DataList[v.index]: Source

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/180956/access-array-attribute-via-integer-attribute-in-lightning and https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/198034/using-an-auraiteration-index-as-an-array-accessor.

Answer (score 0):

You can't access a dynamic element this way. Instead, you could write another attribute and use that as the value to bind to:

```
<aura:attribute name="indexData" type="Object" />
<aura:handler name="change" value="{!v.index}" action="{!updateIndexData}" />
<aura:handler name="change" value="{!v.DataList}" action="{!updateIndexData}" />
...
<c:myChild_CMP obj="{!v.indexData}" />
```

---

```
updateIndexData: function(component, event, helper) {
    var dataList = component.get("v.DataList"),
        index = component.get("v.index"),
        data = dataList && index >= 0? dataList[index]: null;
    component.set("v.indexData", data);
},
```

---

Comment: I want to get dynamic value of DataList on component level, because I have some input data which I have to store in the DataList. Is there any way to access the DataList directly in component using index ?

Comment: @user2202077 Yes, but you *cannot*. You will need to use either aura:iteration, an attribute as shown here, or something else.

Comment: @user2202077 As long as they're all in the same namespace, this solution should work, I believe, and other solutions, such as using aura:iteration, should also work. Or, come up with an entirely different solution. The point is, you can't access an index dynamically. Your question is itself an [x-y problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Accessing a dynamic index directly is impossible.